# Set Background Image to shape using fabric.js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, konva

I need to set background image to fabric.js shape object, just like how we do using CSS `background-image:url("image.jpg");`, I tried using fill property with fabric.Pattern but it results in zoomed and blurred image:

```
//here, currentObj is the selected shape
fabric.Image.fromURL(img, function (img) {
    let fill = new fabric.Pattern({ source: img.getElement(), repeat: "repeat" });
    currentObj.data.set("fill", fill);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

I tried with clipPath/clipTo but it seems to work on the whole canvas rather than a single object. I need the image to cover the object with its background (just like background-size:cover in css). Is there any possibility?

[image]